# TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index in using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to make a decision with if function in pytorch. my code is as follows:

```py
if lengths > StateHCVRP.TB[veh] and torch.sum(self.PM[:, veh])==0:
    Vehicle_f[torch.arange(batch_size), veh] = 1
```

lengths has size `[1024,5]` TB has size `5` and PM has size `[1024,5]`

I get this error:

```py
if lengths > StateHCVRP.TB[veh] and torch.sum(self.PM[:, veh])==1:
```

```
TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What type is `veh`? The error message suggests it's not an integer tensor.